# Connect to LightBlue peripheral mode

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, lightblue

I used LightBlue app on an IOS Devices (iPhone 4s, iOS 6.1.3) in peripheral mode and another IOS device (iPhone 4s, iOS 6.1.3) in a central mode.

I'm using [BTLE Transfer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) example code from Apple, it's working properly on these two devices. However, It does not work on LightBlue. As I just want to develop a simple app that read data from Blood Pressure Device, I've just changed the following service and characteristic UUID  in Transfer.h file

## define TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID           @"1810"

## define TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID    @"2A49" // just read value

My plan is going to clone a real device structure on LightBlue and then develop a central app to connect with LightBlue peripheral (I think it then will work with real devices because I donot have any real device at the moment). I set a device as a peripheral and the second one will install modified app (from apple sample) as a central or client.

The following delegate method provided by Apple:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    // Reject any where the value is above reasonable range
    if (RSSI.integerValue > -15) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Reject if the signal strength is too low to be close enough (Close is around -22dB)
    if (RSSI.integerValue < -35) {
        return;
    }
    
    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);
    
    // Ok, it's in range - have we already seen it?
    if (self.discoveredPeripheral != peripheral) {
        
        // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it
        self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;
        
        // And connect
        NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
        self.connectingPeripheral=peripheral; // this line of code I have added as recommended from a member
    }
}
```

And the problem is, this delegate method have been fired and log panel display "Discovered LightBlue at -32".It likely cannot connect to the Lightblue peripheral as I cannot see the output of the line of code  NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);

All suggestion are welcome and highly appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution? did it work? I am trying to do something similar but I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you find a way to make this work? I am also doing this kind of approach.